# How to trigger file download from document root upon ajax success

Tags: javascript, django-templates, django-views

If I copy my file to document root, how do I start downloading a file upon an AJAX success function?

I tried this but I don't know how to specify the document root path here.

```
success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            if(msg.zip == 'ok'){                    
                window.open('file:'+msg.logpath);
            }              
        },
```

Suppose I have a file named test.txt in my document root, is there way I could download it on the browser

Comment: Most browsers will not let you randomly download a document to it - that would be a massive security problem. Usually a document can only be downloaded as the result of a user action (clicking on a button for example).

Comment: I agree. I am indeed clicking a button. The AJAX success response has the file path to download. It's the next step that I am looking for after getting the path in success function.